Add code suggestion box in a standalone github comment
When reviewing a PR in GitHub, we can provide suggestions to one or more lines of code and it will look in a box similar to something like this:

Is there a way to add the same box suggestion in a standalone GitHub comment?
I know there is something similar to this, but I don't like the way it looks:

